# Get all request to single socket in reuse-socket group

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have the following code. When the client sends request to 7.7.7.7:3000, sometimes I get that in s1 and sometimes I get that in s2. I want only s1 to get the request all the time. Is this possible ?

```
import socket

s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s1.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, True)
s1.bind(('', 3000))

s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s2.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, True)
s2.bind(('7.7.7.7', 3000))

data, addr = s1.recvfrom(1024)
s2.sendto("dinesh".encode(), addr)
```